# Go to Other Forms with RadioButton in C#

Tags: c#

in c# windowsForm App, I have 3 Forms and in first form I have 2 RadioButtons. I want to go to Form2 if RadioButton1 selected and to go to Form3 if RadioButtn2 selected.

How can I do that?!

Comment: just use `CheckedChanged` event of the radio button to detect which radio is selected and launch the Forms

Comment: It's technically possible, but take a moment to think about the UI design. As a user I would not expect selecting a radio button to open another form. Buttons can do that, but radio buttons? Unexpected behaviour is usually not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `CheckedChanged` event of the radio button to detect which radio is selected and launch the Forms

```
   private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
            new Form1().Show();
        else
            new Form2().Show();
    }
```